# Regular expression: OR does not work with complete words

Tags: r

When I try to do an OR with two or more COMPLETE words, it does not work.

```
sentence <- "My cat is on the sofa"
grepl("\\bcat\\b", sentence)
[1] TRUE

grepl("\\bct\\b", sentence)
[1] FALSE

grepl("\\bct\\b || \\bsofa\\b", sentence)
[1] TRUE

grepl("\\bct\\b || \\bsof\\b", sentence)
[1] TRUE
```

It does not work with parenthesis either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` is an operator in R, for regex you have to use single `|`

```
grepl("\\bct\\b | \\bsof\\b", sentence)
#[1] FALSE
```